# List gitlab projects using API

Tags: gitlab-api

I'm trying to get list of gitlab projects I've been invited to.

Using https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/:user_id/projects I can get only list of projects I've created. But how can I get projects that I'm as a member but that I didn't create?

using endpoint https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects with membership parameter didn't help.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to find a way to do this?

Comment: nope and nobody can give me answer even on gitlab forum

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [Gitlab's API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-user-projects):

> Only the projects in the user’s (specified in `user_id`) namespace are returned. Projects owned by the user in any group or subgroups are not returned. An empty list is returned if a profile is set to private.

So the `user.projects.list()` will only return projects created by yourself (i.e. projects that are located in your own namespace `./{yourUser user_id}/projects`. A working around this would be:

1. get a list of all groups you've access to

```
groups = api.groups.list(min_access_level=50)
```

2. create an object of the user of interest

```
user = api.users.get(id=user_of_interest.id)
```

3. filter the list of all groups to get just the ones that the `user_of_interest` is present

```
groups = [g for g in groups if user in g.members.list(get_all=True)]
```

4. get a list of all projects from these groups

```
projects = [api.projects.get(id=p.id) for g in groups for p in g.projects.list()]
```

- Note here that we need to convert the `GroupProject` objects to `Project` objects

5. Filter this list with just the projects to which the user of interest has access to

```
projects = [p for p in projects if user in p.members_all.list()]
```

- Note that if you use `p.members.list()` instead of `p.members_all.list()` you will only get projects where this user is a direct member of

So, putting everything together:

```
import gitlab

api = gitlab.Gitlab(url=host, private_token=token)
api.auth()

groups = api.groups.list(min_access_level=50)
user = api.users.get(id=user_of_interest.id)
groups = [g for g in groups if user in g.members.list(get_all=True)]
projects = [api.projects.get(id=p.id) for g in groups for p in g.projects.list()]
projects = [p for p in projects if user in p.members_all.list()]
```